# Can someone please explain 2.5-opt heuristic (also known as 2h-opt) in basic terms?

Tags: search, optimization, graph-theory, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I am trying to find information that accurately explains 2.5-opt, but I am coming up short.  I have read Jon Bentleys "Fast Algorithms for Geometric Traveling Salesman Problems", as well as several other sources on the web.  I understand 2-opt and 3-opt.

Given edges AB and CD, one variation of 2.5-opt appears to be to move C between AB
another variation I have seen seems to imply moving A between CD
and yet another variation seems to imply moving B between CD

The only thing I am sure of, is you are moving a single point, between no other points, and there are no reversals that need to be done.  I am looking for someone with good knowledge to set me straight on what are the two moves to consider with 2.5-opt.

Comment: Do you know of a link to the paper that's not blocked by a paywall?